# No merges visible in Eclipse Subversive Plugin revision graph

Tags: svn, merge, subversive

as mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/revision_graph.php) the Eclipse SVN plugin *Subversive* is able to show the revision graph for any file under SVN control. However, I don't see any outgoing or incoming 'Merges' within the graph. The text known as 'mergeinfo' coming from the svn properties *svn:mergeinfo* are shown in the textbox but without any dotted or continuous line between the both revisions in the graph. Furthermore, is it important *how* the merge is performed ? Some colleagues told me, that it's necessary to commit the whole directory after a merge operation for a single file instead the file only ??? But in my case (Eclipse Kepler, Subversive 1.1 and SVN 1.8) neither committing the directory nor the single file leads to inter-connected branches in the revision graph.

Kind regards

Dominik